# Facebook App - Can an app have more than 1 Webhook URL setup with it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks, facebook-webhooks

I'm currently developing a Facebook app, which will subscribe to Pages in order to pick up activity on the "feed" of the page. So any posts and comments will trigger the Webhook. Currently it seems that you can only set 1 Webhook URL per application. What I want is the ability for the user to install the Facebook app against their page and be able to change the Webhook URL to point to their own URL. Is it possible to do this? I thought it would be having read the following from the Facebook developers website (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks#subscriptions-edge),
[image: subscription_edges]

As it says you can "create new subscriptions or modify existing ones" I was under the assumption that you can add more than 1 Webhook URL. Can anyone help and confirm whether what I'm trying to do is not possible with the current setup from Facebook please?

Comment: No, that is not possible. (And I don’t see how that would even make sense either, because then each and every single user of your app would have to have the actual coding that handles those updates residing in their own system. In that case, they might as well use their own app id to begin with, I don’t know what they would need your app for then ...)

Comment: If the app they are using is software programmed by myself, which they are hosting then I will be in control of what the program will do with the Facebook posts from their page. The software will then use that data and run an action based on its purpose.

Comment: If they are hosting your code themselves, then they should use it with their own app id.